# UILabel becomes nil when unwrapping

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a two UILabels, one for keeping track of time, and one for score. For some reason, when I try to unwrap the UILabel outside of ViewDidLoad() it gives me the error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value", which means that the UILabel has a value of nil. If I unwrap the UILanel inside ViewDidLoad it doesn't give me this error, but when I unwrap it outside like in addScore it does... Also it doesn't matter which UILabel I try to unwrap, they both give me this issue. How should I fix it?

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

// Both of the Labels
var timeLabel: UILabel?
var scoreLabel: UILabel?

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
        //self.addScore(3)
    }

    // Creating the TimeLabel
    timeLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.width/4, view.frame.height/10))
    timeLabel!.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    timeLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 50)
    timeLabel!.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    timeLabel!.startCountdown(10)

    // Creating the ScoreLabel
    scoreLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(100, 0, view.frame.width/4, view.frame.height/10))
    scoreLabel!.text = "0"
    scoreLabel!.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    scoreLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 50)
    scoreLabel!.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()


    self.view.addSubview(timeLabel!)
    self.view.addSubview(scoreLabel!)

}
// This is run externally after the view is loaded
func addScore (points: Int){
    // This line is the one that gives me an error
    self.scoreLabel!.addScore(points)
}
```

Comment: If you dont mind me asking. Why are you force unwrapping the label?

Comment: Are you talking about the line where i add the score?

Comment: No I mean, Change your label declaration to, 
var timeLabel: UILabel!
var scoreLabel: UILabel! and remove the ! from everywhere else.

Comment: oh I didn't realize i could do that, what does it do?

Comment: It unwraps your label on declaration. So you dont have to force unwrap it everywhere else.

Comment: Thanks, ill fix that